# Remove dynamic timer

Tags: c#, dictionary, timer

I'm trying to remove a timer before it has ended. If I click button 1 the timer starts, but if I click button 2 before the timer has elapsed I still get a message from the tick event.

I need to have multiple timers with the date as the key in the dictionary.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here please.

```
private Dictionary<string, System.Timers.Timer> timers = new Dictionary<string, System.Timers.Timer>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dateTimeString = "19/03/2013 05:11:23"
    var myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Interval = 30000;
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    timers.Add(dateTimeString, myTimer);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timers.Remove("19/03/2013 05:11:23");
}

public void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Timer tick");
    ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      timers[launchTime].Enabled = false;
      timers.Remove(launchTime);
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the speedy and accurate reply. I have been trying to work that out for 2 or more hours.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your timer to null.

Comment: Setting the timer to null won't necessarily remove it. You have to remove all references in order for it to be eligible for garbage collection. It's better to disable and then dispose of the timer. Then you *know* it won't tick again, even if it takes a while for the garbage collector to clean it up.